# Where clause in haskell function without parameters

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

```
substitute':: (Eq a)=> a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
substitute' x y = map substituteOne
                  where
                    substituteOne x' | x == x'   = y
                                     | otherwise = x'
```

So, the point of this function is, that it takes two inputs of type a and a list of type a and substitutes all elements in list [a] that are from the "first" a with the "second" a. At least that is what the task description says.

I already implemented a recursive version, but a function with a where clause is also needed.

So THAT is the solution for it. Somehow I have questions:

1. how can substituteOne in the second line work without any parameters?
2. where do we give a list as input? or where do we state WHAT we do with that list? I mean compiling and eecuting it works, but somehow I don't see it
3. what is x' ? it is never defined anywhere, we just start working with it somehow (maybe refers also to question 1)
4. map needs a function and a list, so that it works. here we have map function _. refers maybe to 2., but what would be the output of substituteOne x' ?

If needed, result looks like this:

```
substitute' 5 10 [1, 5, 2, 5, 3, 5]
[1,10,2,10,3,10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **(1)** how can `substituteOne` in the second line work without any parameters?
>   **(2)** where do we give a list as input? or where do we state *what* we do with that list? I mean compiling and executing it works, but somehow I don’t see it

The parameters are still there; this is [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying) at work. Consider the [section of an infix operator](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) `(+1)`, which is a special case of [partial application](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application). Given a number, it produces a number that is one greater. Witness:

```hs
λ> :t (+1)
(+1) :: Num a => a -> a
```

We could define a function to increment all elements of a list by naming the list

```hs
λ> :t \l -> map (+1) l
\l -> map (+1) l :: Num b => [b] -> [b]
```

but that turns out to be unnecessary because of [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying).

```hs
λ> :t map (+1)
map (+1) :: Num b => [b] -> [b]
```

This is *functional* programming, after all. With Haskell, we manipulate functions as easily as other languages manipulate strings.

> **(3)** what is `x'`? it is never defined anywhere, we just start working with it somehow (maybe refers also to question 1)

But you *do* define `x'` as a parameter of `substituteOne`!

Consider the type of `map`:

```hs
λ> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Its first argument is a function of one parameter. For your program to typecheck, the types have to line up. We can emphasize this for `substituteOne` by adding an optional type annotation — but have to work a bit harder (by enabling the [scoped type variables](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables) extension) because `substituteOne` is an inner function with references to the outer scope,

```hs
substitute':: forall a. Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
substitute' x y = map substituteOne
                  where
                    substituteOne :: a -> a
                    substituteOne x' | x == x'   = y
                                     | otherwise = x'
```

> **(4)** `map` needs a function and a list, so that it works. here we have `map` function `_`. refers maybe to 2., but what would be the output of `substituteOne x'`?

Using unnamed arguments at the point of application as your code does with `map substituteOne` is known as [pointfree style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree). In your case, there are two invisible “points” or variable names: the argument to `substituteOne` and the list argument to `map`.

You could be explicit about everything, as in

```hs
substitute'' :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
substitute'' x y l = map (\x' -> if x == x' then y else x') l
```

but that is much more cluttered in comparison.

The values produced by `substituteOne` are collected in the list that results from `map`.

Answer (score 1):

`substitute` has type `a -> a -> [a] -> [a]`, which means it takes *one* argument and returns a function of type `a -> [a] -> [a]`. This is because `(->)` is right-associative, and the above type is equivalent to `a -> (a -> [a] -> [a])`.

Since function application is left-associative, a call like `substitute x y` is equivalent to `(substitute x) y`; `y` is the argument to the function returned by `substitute x`.

When one writes

```
substitute x y = ...
```

that is syntactic sugar for

```
substitute = \x -> \y -> ...
```

Further, since `map substituteOne'` has type `[a] -> [a]`, that makes it a suitable value for `substitute x y` to return.

Answer (score 0):

`substitute1` takes a parameter `x'`. The bits between the `|` and `=` characters are guard conditions. Since this particular function has only one condition you could rewrite it like this:

```
substitute1 x' = if x == x' then y else x'
```

Because it is in the `where` clause `substitute1` also has access to the parameters `x` and `y` of the main function.